# OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms package breaks Resource.Designer.cs?

Tags: c#, android, charts, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I'm trying to use the OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms package in my shared Xamarin.Forms project. I added the OxyPlot packages with the NuGet package manager in both the portable and the platform specific (Android) projects like descriped at:

http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms.html

Then I initialized the OxyPlot renderers in the Android project. Now, when I try to start the App the Resource.Designer.cs file is generated, but I get hundreds of errors like so:

```
Error   CS0117  'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 'mediaRouteSettingsDrawable' OxyPlotShared.Droid \OxyPlotShared\OxyPlotShared.Droid\Resources\Resource.Designer.cs
```

I use Xamarin.Forms v2.2.0.31 and all OxyPlot packages in version 1.0.0-unstable1983.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are 2 different project templates: **Portable** and **Shared**. In your post you mention both of them, so be clear about which one you're using. The specific example you're following is for a **Portable** project template. After adding the **OxyPlot Nuget Package**, I had to manually add **OxyPlot** and **OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms** to the **References** of the **Portable** one. After that, it worked just fine. I'm using Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.6482 and OxyPlot 1.0.0-unstable1983.

I added the `PlotView` using code:

App.cs:

```
 public App()
    {
        PlotModel plotModel = new PlotModel { PlotAreaBackground = OxyColors.LightYellow };
        plotModel.Series.Add(new FunctionSeries(Math.Sin, -10, 10, 0.1, "sin(x)"));

        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            Content = new PlotView {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                Model = plotModel
            }
        };
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It works with Xamarin.Forms 2.0.0.x and even with 2.1.0.x but it does not work with Xamarin 2.2.0.31. Oxyplot.Xamarin.Android library needs to be fixed in order to be compatible to AppCompact 23.3.0

Comment: Yeah OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.1.0.0-unstable1983 (Android) is "Breaking Bad" my spirit rolling back to 1883